# Canon T5 photos are black

Tags: canon, sensor

My Canon Rebel T5 recently started shooting all photos with a pink to black gradient.

[image: All photos come out like this]

I have taken off the lens and confirmed that the shutter does actuate. This effect is seen on all of my lenses.
In live view mode it goes from completely white to pink to black and it stays black.

I have reset camera settings and formatted 2 different SD cards and it continues to do this.

This effect occurs across all ISO, Shutter speed, and Aperture sizes.
All photos that the camera takes are the same pink black photo.

When i take the battery out and left the camera for more than 24hrs with out a battery or SD card and the first photo taken after 24 hrs comes out perfectly fine, all other photos revert to pink black.

[edit]Camera is no longer under warranty.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have additional lenses you can test with?

Comment: It does this with all of my lenses. Also does this without a lens..

Comment: Is the camera under warranty?

Answer (score 2):

Used Canon EOS Utility to open live view and left it in live view for 1 hour and the camera eventually returned to normal. This was after resetting camera settings and updating the firmware. With a blank formatted SD card. It appears to have been just a bug.

Comment: Maybe, or your shutter could be failing.  Are you sure that both the front and rear curtains opened?  Because this is what I would expect if only one of them opened—a slight light leak around the top of one curtain.

Comment: Thanks for the info but in live view both curtains were open and I could see the entire sensor. Sensor went from all black to black and white to artifacting and then returned to normal.